# A permutation $\sigma= (15673)(8246)(357)$ written as a product of conjoined cycles.

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutation-cycles

On $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ the following product of cycles is given

$$\sigma = (15673)(8246)(357)$$

The cycles above are conjoined.

> 1) Does this mean it's just one cycle?
>
> 2) Can $\sigma$ be written as a product of disjoint cycles. If it can, how should one do it?

PS This is actually not a problem but a question I have.

Comment: The way you wrote $\sigma$, some elements of $A$ (e.g., $5, 6, 7$) appear in more than one cycle, so the cycles are not disjoint; every permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles; figure out where $\sigma$ takes $1$, where $\sigma$ takes that element, etc., until you get back to $1$, and that's one cycle; then look for an element not in that cycle that $\sigma$ permutes, etc.

Comment: 1 $\rightarrow$ 5 $\rightarrow$ ... I stop here. Because 5 is in two cycles. How to proceed from here? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: When two cycles are juxtaposed, they are composed:  first one, then the other; there are different conventions as to the order:  some would say what you wrote means $5\mapsto6$ (the left cycle) and then $6\mapsto8$ (the middle cycle) so $\sigma:5\mapsto8$; others would say $5\mapsto7$ (the right cycle) and then $7\mapsto3$ (the left cycle) so $\sigma:5\mapsto3$

Comment: @J. W. Tanner I'm not sure I understand your point.

Comment: I tried to explain in my answer below; let me know if it's still not clear

Comment: Thanks for tour time. I understand this!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote helpful answers and accept one of them, @Xenusi!

Answer (score 0):

In this context, conjoint probably means that the cycles are not disjoint, i.e., some of their elements overlap.

Any permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles. To get the product you are after, you can first write it as a product of $2$-cycles.

First $3$ is sent to $5$ in the rightmost cycle, and later, in the leftmost cycle, $5$ is sent to $6$. This means that $3$ is sent to $6$, so you get the first $2$-cycle $(3~6)$. Then you look at what happens to $6$, and find it is sent to $8$, so you get $(6~8)$. You now continue with $8$.

After having done all, you get exactly eight $2$-cycles like this:

$$ (3~6) (6~8) (8~2) (2~4) (4~7) (7~1) (1~5) (5~3) = (36824715) $$

This is indeed a product of disjoint cycles. The number of cycles happens to be $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Every permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles.

$\sigma = (15673)(8246)(357)$ is not expressed as a product of disjoint cycles, since $3, 5, 6, $ and $7$ are elements in more than one cycle.

When two cycles are juxtaposed, they are composed.  There are different conventions as to which permutation is applied first.  Here I will take the convention that the rightmost permutation acts first.

The rightmost cycle $(357)$ does not affect $1$, nor does the middle cycle $(8246)$, but the leftmost cycle $(15673)$ maps $1\mapsto5$, so $\sigma:1\mapsto5$.  The rightmost cycle maps $5\mapsto7$ and the leftmost cycle maps $7\mapsto3$, so $\sigma:5\mapsto3$.  The rightmost cycle maps $3\mapsto5$ and the leftmost cycle maps $5\mapsto6$, so $\sigma:3\mapsto6$.  The rightmost cycle does not affect $6$, but the middle cycle maps it to $8$, so $\sigma:6\mapsto8$.  The rightmost cycle does not affect $8$ either, but the middle cycle maps $8\mapsto2$, so $\sigma:8\mapsto2$.  Similarly, $\sigma:2\mapsto4$, $\sigma:4\mapsto7$, and $\sigma:7\to1$.

Thus, $\sigma$ can be written as $(15368247)$ in disjoint cycle notation.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the permutation left-to-right, let $f=(15673), g=(8246), h=(357)$. Then $\sigma=fgh$.

We have that $\sigma$ is given by the following calculations:

$$\begin{align}
1&\stackrel{f}{\mapsto} 5\stackrel{g}{\mapsto}5\stackrel{h}{\mapsto} 7 \\
7&\stackrel{f}{\mapsto} 3\stackrel{g}{\mapsto}3\stackrel{h}{\mapsto} 5 \\
5&\stackrel{f}{\mapsto} 6\stackrel{g}{\mapsto}8\stackrel{h}{\mapsto} 8 \\
8&\stackrel{f}{\mapsto} 8\stackrel{g}{\mapsto}2\stackrel{h}{\mapsto} 2 \\
2&\stackrel{f}{\mapsto} 2\stackrel{g}{\mapsto}4\stackrel{h}{\mapsto} 4 \\
4&\stackrel{f}{\mapsto} 4\stackrel{g}{\mapsto}6\stackrel{h}{\mapsto} 6 \\
6&\stackrel{f}{\mapsto} 7\stackrel{g}{\mapsto}7\stackrel{h}{\mapsto} 3 \\
3&\stackrel{f}{\mapsto} 1\stackrel{g}{\mapsto}1\stackrel{h}{\mapsto} 1 \\
\end{align}$$

so $\sigma=(17582463)$ (but note, again, that this is reading left-to-right; the right-to-left case is handled in other answers and is, for this $\sigma$, different).